# Does gravity cause the gravity of another mass to curve?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, gravitational-lensing

For example say star 1 is at position x, however star 2 causes gravitational lensing on star 1's light that is traveling toward you and you now see star 1 at position y. Will star 1's gravity move you toward position x or y?

Please use layman terms

Answer (score 1):

Toward position y.  Gravity couples to itself (Einstein's equations are nonlinear), so yes, gravity can cause itself to curve.  Another way to see it is that photons and gravitons are both massless and so they both travel along identical null geodesics, so wherever you see light coming from, you'll feel the gravity from the light source pulling you in the exact same direction.

Comment: are you saying that mass lensing may affect the gravity in the same way it does with light ?

Comment: @igael Yep, indeed.

Comment: yes, you are right, it is what GR says ...